# how to execute msbuild.exe command using winform c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, msbuild

I want to execute msbuild.exe command from winform c# on button click

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the reg key
    RegistryKey regKey;
    regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4");

    // get the CurrentInstallFolder
    string msBuildToolsPath = (string)regKey.GetValue("MSBuildToolsPath");
```

I have updated my code used following code to execute msbuild it is working but screen closed out once all execute , I should have to see screen open

```
var solutionFile = item.ToString();
var msbuildPath = msBuildToolsPath;

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Arguments = String.Format("\"{0}\" /nologo", solutionFile),
        FileName = Path.Combine(msbuildPath, "msbuild.exe")
};

var proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495170/executing-custom-commands-from-command-prompt-in-winform-c-sharp

Comment: duplicate questions are similar but my code is different please check updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe");
```

Comment: unable to build solution using above can you please more elaborate ?

Comment: dont know how that can be an acceptable answer because of the hardcoded path. How about that:

**1.** add Reference of "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core"

**2.** var path = ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToBuildTools(ToolLocationHelper.CurrentToolsVersion).ToString();